# Insert statement takes too long to finish

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, insert

I am trying to Insert some data from one table to another in SQL Server , but it takes too long to finish even when **affected rows** are 0.

Below is the query I am using to Insert :

```
INSERT INTO Table_1 (Prop_1, Prop_2)
    SELECT @passedParam , Prop_2 
    FROM Table_2
    WHERE Prop_1 = @passedParam - 1 
      AND Prop_2 NOT IN (SELECT Prop_2 
                         FROM Table_2
                         WHERE Prop_1 = @passedParam)
```

Some additional information:

- This query is inside a stored procedure which takes `@passedParam` as a parameter
- `Table_2` contains around 28,000 rows
- I am filtering `Table_2` and inserting result into `Table_1` based on some logic. `Prop_1` and `Prop_2` are regular columns, not PK or FK and datatypes are `INT` and `BIGINT`
- I have commented out every other statement in the stored procedure, only this one takes so much time (Up to 50 sec to finish even when affected rows are equal to 0)

Can anyone explain what the issue is, and why it takes so long to finish?

Please tell if there is a faster way to insert data into the table.

Comment: Could it be a slow trigger? Otherwise you need to upload a query plan [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and give us a link to it.

Comment: Please share a query plan with the above link. Please also [edit] your question with table and index definitions

Answer (score 1):

Try this way :

```
INSERT INTO Table_1 
       (Prop_1,      Prop_2)
SELECT @passedParam, Prop_2 
FROM   Table_2
WHERE  Prop_1 = @passedParam - 1 
EXCEPT
SELECT Prop_2, @passedParam 
FROM   Table_2
WHERE  Prop_1 = @passedParam;
```

Comment: If that makes the slightest bit of difference, I would be highly surprised. An `EXCEPT` is transformed into the same anti-join as `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN` so you will get the same query plan